# maximum independent set in d-regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Does anyone know whether the maximum independent set problem is NP-hard in triangle free d-regular graphs and if it's NP-hard for all d larger than some threshold t? Can anyone provide a reference also?

Comment: The intuition would be that you have NP-hardness already for d=3. see e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10001974 which goes about similar questions